# How to get hold of the Message (payload) in Spring Integration ErrorHandler?

Tags: spring

I am using DefaultMessageListenerContainer to configure message-driven-channel-adapter to read  a message from a queue, process it and and post it to a different queue using outbound-channel-adapter.
If I encounter any exception (such as javax.jms.JMSException: Message exceeded maximum size) while posting the message to the outbound queue, I want to handle it in errorHandler (property of DefaultMessageListenerContainer) and notify the receiver.

I am able to get the exception stack trace in the errorHandler, but I am not sure which message caused that exception. Is there any way I can get hold of the message/payload that caused the exception in the errorHandler?

```
public class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        // Get the payload???
            // Log the exception
            // Notify the receiver
}
```

Thanks!
Guru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Integration adds an error handler to the DefaultMessageListenerContainer automatically when you define a message-driven-channel-adapter.  Errors appear on a channel called "errorChannel" and you can treat these just as you would any other message in Spring Integration.  Just add a channel anywhere in your configuration called "errorChannel" and you can add components from there.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#namespace-errorhandler

Remember that handling the error will successfully complete any ongoing JMS transaction, so remember to throw it after you've handled it so that the JMS transaction rolls back.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works

```
public class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

   public void handleError(Throwable t) {

        if (throwable instanceof MessageHandlingException) {
            MessageHandlingException exception = (MessageHandlingException) throwable;
            if (exception != null) {
                Message<?> message = exception.getFailedMessage();
                payload = (String) message.getPayload();
            }
        }
   ...
}
```